# Python : replace a word in a dictionnary

Tags: python

i receive the following dictionnary:

```
response={"a":"17","b":"4","c":34,"d":65,"e":162,"m":false,"M":true}
```

I want to extract.
`response["b"]`
but I cant

> error = NameError: name 'false' is not defined

I guess it's because it's false and not False.

I have tried to replace false by 0 and true by 1

Meth 1 > does not work

```
if message["m"] == 'true' message["m"]=1 else message["m"]=0
if message["M"] == 'true' message["m"]=1 else message["M"]=0
```

Meth 2

```
message = list(map(lambda x: 1 if x is 'true' else 1, asset_update))
```

neither work.
Basically, I cannot get "into" the dictionnary as the case issue throws an arror.
How can I repalce the dictionnary true/false with 0/1 as soo as I receive it ot make it "python compliant"?

Comment: Use `True` and `False`. Note the case.

Comment: is not a dictionary, it's a json string. `response = json.loads(response)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some others suggest in the comments of your post, your *dictionary* might actually be a [JSON object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Note the lower case `false`.

These look very similar to Python dictionaries but are not equivalent, and can be easily used in Python with

```py
import json
# response is our JSON object
py_dict = json.loads(response)
# py_dict now contains the equivalent Python dictionary
```

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed a JSON object. Bless you all !